# Decide if this series converges using derivatives

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence

I need to find whether this series converges or diverges:

$\sum_{0}^\infty\frac{ln(n+1)-ln(n)}{\sqrt[2]{n} }$

The clue is that at some point it is necesary to use calculus, specificly derivatives.

All I discovered is fact that it covereges by Raabe–Duhamel's test but I am unable to prove it as calculations are awful

It's a task for first year student in Poland

Comment: first year in what country?

Comment: Comparison test together with a simple estimate $$ \log(n+1) - \log n = \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} \leq \frac{1}{n} $$ (which can be obtained equally by the mean value theorem) is enough to conclude the convergence of the series.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the sum starts at $n=1$, otherwise $\log(0)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{0}}$ lead to some issues.
By summation by parts,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\log(N+1)}{\sqrt{N}}-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\log(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) $$
hence the original series is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)} $$
whose general term behaves like $\frac{\log n}{n^{3/2}}$, that is the general term of an absolutely convergent series, by the $p$-test. Or, simply through $0\leq \log(1+x)\leq x$ for any $x\in[0,1]$,
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}=\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right).$$